# Positive integer solutions of $3^b-2p^a=1$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Famous Catalan's conjecture states: the only solution in the natural numbers of
$x^{a}-y^{b}=1$
for $a, b > 1$, $x, y > 0$ is $x = 3$, $a = 2$, $y = 2$, $b = 3$.

My problem is dealing with a similar equation:

$3^b-2p^a=1$

where $b$ is an odd prime and $a$ is a positive integer larger than $1$, $p$ is a Zsigmondy prime divisor of $3^b-1$ (that is $p\mid 3^b-1$, but $p\nmid 3^i-1$ for positive integers $i<b$).

**My question is: could we find all positive integers solutions of this equation?**

Any explanation, references, suggestion and examples are appreciated.

Comment: do you want to find all solutions with $a=1$ too?

Comment: There seem to be a lot of solutions with $a=1$.  With $a>1$ we have $3^5-2.11^2=1$, and it's hard to find other solutions. The first few with $a=1$ are $b=3,7,13,71$.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Dave Benson's opinion. It do seem to be a lot of solutions with $a=1$. Just like the solutions for Catalan's conjecture when $a=1$ or $b=1$. So, I intend to find solutions when $a>1$. @FedorPetrov

Comment: The next two with $a=1$ are $b=103,541$. This is Sloane A028491.

Comment: J. Brillhart et al., Factorizations of $b^n \pm 1$. Contemporary Mathematics, Vol. 22, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 2nd edition, 1985.

Comment: Thanks very much. The reference is very helpful. @DaveBenson